# how to calculate member offset in c++ class

Tags: c++

example

```
class B {
public:
   int y;
private:
   int x;
};
class A : public B {
public:
   int a;
private:
   int b;
};
```

how to calculate A.b's offset in some object of A ?

one method was to use gdb, but it was slow.

is there other method works which don't need to execute/compile the program ?

Comment: If C++ object has no virtual methods then member's offset equals to `ptrdiff_t(&obj.member) - ptrdiff_t(&obj)` or inside of method you may use `ptrdiff_t(this->member) - ptrdiff_t(this)`.

Comment: Offset from what? There are two possibilities: the offset from the start of the object (i.e., where in memory things are located), or the offset from the `this` pointer. The `this` pointer doesn't necessarily point at the start of the object. This assumes we're not dealing with virtual bases, because members of the base class do not have a fixed offset in derived types.

Answer (score 3):

> how to calculate A.b's offset in some object of A ?

You can use the standard macro `offsetof` if the class is standard layout, or your language implementation supports it for non-standard layout classes (your class is not standard layout):

```
std::size_t offset = offsetof(A, b);
```

> is there other method works which don't need to execute/compile the program ?

You could read the ABI specification of your language implementation. If you understand all of it, the calculation should be possible with basic addition and multiplication.

The simple cases are easy to calculate. The rules can be quite complex however and it may not be easy to accurately identify the cases which are simple.

Comment: Do note that this is UB (pre C++17)/conditionally supported(C++17+) for the OP's case.  Their class is not is not a standard layout type.

Answer (score 1):

Member's offset equals to

```
ptrdiff_t(&obj.member) - ptrdiff_t(&obj)
```

or inside of class' method, especially if your member is private, you may use

```
ptrdiff_t(&this->member) - ptrdiff_t(this)
```

The only thing to take into account is if there are virtual methods then members offsets are not 0-based. At 0-th offset there is usually pointer to virtual methods table. If there are no virtual methods then offsets are 0-based (0 is offset of first member of most base parent class), at least I never had non-0-based offsets for non-virtual classes.

Full example code:

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jY/RasMwDEXf9RWCwWgeUvpcl8D2I8V2nE4jsY2tlJbQb8/krutaVuhejHykq3tlY6xtr/1unl9oiCExbihkTk4PDVyRzdy2rmtgzOR36PXgctTWoXAFIBtyxnecII6mJ7sGRCTPeFQQE@01uys6KDipi@IN1/iteCTWqlSRU0tdt2UM8ppFhTb4zDhhcjwm/zuweOUPynVjKqxvaIGVwtOfJOacBEo5aPKyeSotSRXM59lbrEa5flPA8sdevs63/f3ATYgyq@8jFPY/4fGp8HL1SsLDPH8B)

```
#import <iostream>
#import <cstddef>
using namespace std;

class B {
public:
   int y;
private:
   int x;
};
class A : public B {
public:
   int a;
   ptrdiff_t off_b() const { return ptrdiff_t(&this->b) - ptrdiff_t(this); }
private:
   int b;
};

int main() {
    A obj;
    cout << obj.off_b() << endl;
    cout << ptrdiff_t(&obj.a) - ptrdiff_t(&obj) << endl;
    cout << ptrdiff_t(&obj.y) - ptrdiff_t(&obj) << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
12
8
0
```

Here is same [code but with virtual methods](https://tio.run/##jZDBTsMwDIbvfgpLSGg9FHFupkrsRVCSpsOoTaPEmZiq8uolHhtscIBL5Hz5/ft3bAi1HbTfr@sdjWGKjFuaEkenxxa@kE3cda5vISfye/R6dClo67BwBVAcUsIdzhCyGcg2gIgHipz1gO@7TYXzIog841FBiHTQ7JoLelOwqLPJEzb4afLTT5RaSRU4dtT3z4xTOU2xt5NPjDNGxzn6b8Hmnl8o1a2psL6iAiuFy68k5pQEpBw1eQkuTyXVZF5Ps8uoXD5kK@DhMr5cne@GW8FVCNHq2wjC/td4/LPxvPVjCQ/r@gE). Members start at offset `8` inside this code run, but this offset may differ in different implementations.

Comment: @NathanOliver Are you sure it's required to be standard layout for legality? I'm not sure if even the virtual functions are a problem. The integers have implementation defined values regardless though, so this is technically not guaranteed to give the desired result.

Comment: @eerorika comments removed.  Now I'm not sure.

Comment: @eerorika I always used everywhere (including classes with virtual methods) solution provided in my answer and there were no problems. So you're corret virtual methods are allowed too. Actually what I wanted to say that if there are virtual methods then members offsets are not 0 based.